# How to disable “Seen by” in Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Since recently, Facebook Groups add a "Seen by" feature that show to everyone on that group who have seen that post.

It can be convenient, but it is also a form of privacy invasion.

is there a way to disable it, even if you are not the group admin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Currently there is no way to disable this feature** - a lot of people are in the same boat as you and want the ability to turn on and off the 'seen by' feature however I dont believe Facebook will ever do so.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot turn on or turn off this feature yet. It seems come with the newest groups and is working it's way to older groups. Many people have been talking and annoying about that like [this](http://www.facebook.com/help/community/?id=18832)

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [Magicramki](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36436/16643)'s answer, you can use adblock (only for Chrome, Opera, Safari and Firefox unfortunately, not IE)

## CHROME

- In Chrome, right click on the 'Adblock' icon next to the address bar
  & hit 'Options'
- Click on the 'Customize' tab.
- Click the 'Edit' button next to 'Manually Edit Your Filters'.
- Paste the given link given below & hit 'Save' then close
  the tab.

> `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php`

## FIREFOX

- In Firefox, right click on the 'Adblock' icon & hit 'Filter
  Preferences' or just hit Ctrl+Shift+F in your browser.
- Click on the 'Custom Filters' tab and hit 'Add Filter Group' button.
  Name it anything as you wish.
- Now hit Ctrl+R to view the right pane.
- Click 'Add Filter' button on the right pane and paste the given url
  and hit Enter and Close.

> `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php`

## OPERA

- In Opera, right click on the 'Adblock' icon on the top right corner &
  hit 'Preferences'.
- Now select 'Add Your Own Filters' tab.
- Paste the given link in the first small text box there & hit 'Add
  Filter' and close the tab.

> `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php`

## SAFARI

- In Safari, click on the 'Adblock' icon present just before the
  address bar & hit 'Options'
- Click on the 'Customize' tab.
- Click the 'Edit' button next to 'Manually Edit Your Filters'.
- Paste the given link in the text box there & hit 'Save' then close
  the tab.

> `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php`

Information from the '[crackroach](http://crackroach.blogspot.in/2012/12/hide-seen-at-is-typing-feature-in.html)' blog.

I've found it might be a little different to the above instructions, so here is an image of what I did in chrome:

[image]

I've not tested it yet but I think this should work.

Comment: If you would've tested it, you would have noticed that this only works for the messenger, it does not work for groups.

Comment: I've tested this in firefox. This does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Use Adblock to filter this url: `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php`

> In Chrome, right click on the 'Adblock' icon next to the address bar &
> hit 'Options'
>
> - Click on the 'Customize' tab.
> - Click the 'Edit' button next to 'Manually Edit Your Filters'.
> - Paste the given link in the text box there & hit 'Save' then close the tab.

Source: http://crackroach.blogspot.in/2012/12/hide-seen-at-is-typing-feature-in.html

Comment: We expect answers to be able to stand on their own. An answer that's just a link to a different resource is no answer at all.